# Linear interpolation of given data set

Tags: python, interpolation

I need to interpolate and find the values of a bunch of numbers
`x=np.linspace(0,1.1,23)` 
`y=[1.00,0,0.90,0,0.82,0,0.74,0,0.67,0,0.61,0,0.55,0,0.50,0,0.44,0,0.41,0,0.37,0,0.33]` 
So the values of points x=0,1.1,1.2 etc are known and for points 0.05,0.15,0.25 etc are unknown and i have put them in the list as 0.

Here is my further code:

```
i=1
for i in t1:
   m=(x[i+1]-x[i-1])/(t1[i+1]-t1[i-1])
   y=x[i-1]+m*(t1[i]-t1[i-1])
   x1[i]=y
   i=i+2
print(x1)
```

But i am getting this error:
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64`

How do i fix this?

Comment: What values does t1 hold?

Comment: i am sorry that was an error

Comment: Try ‚for i in y‘

Comment: i=1
for i in x:
   m=(y[i+1]-y[i-1])/(x[i+1]-x[i-1])
   z=y[i-1]+m*(x[i]-x[i-1])
   y[i]=z
   i=i+2
print(y)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1.1, 23)
y = [1.00, 0, 0.90, 0, 0.82, 0, 0.74, 0, 0.67, 0, 0.61,
     0, 0.55, 0, 0.50, 0, 0.44, 0, 0.41, 0, 0.37, 0, 0.33]

for i in range(1, len(y), 2):
    m = (y[i + 1] - y[i - 1]) / (x[i + 1] - x[i - 1])
    b = y[i + 1] - (m * x[i + 1])
    z = m * x[i] + b
    y[i] = round(z, 3)

print(y)
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 0.95, 0.9, 0.86, 0.82, 0.78, 0.74, 0.705, 0.67, 0.64, 0.61, 0.58, 0.55, 0.525, 0.5, 0.47, 0.44, 0.425, 0.41, 0.39, 0.37, 0.35, 0.33]
```